# Newton's derivation of the exponential series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, exponential-function

I am working through the first chapter of Dunham's *Calculus Gallery* (available [here](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s7905.pdf)), and I am trying to see how Newton derived the infinite series for the exponential function, knowing a series for the natural logarithm:

$z = \ln (1 + x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} \dots$

Dunham says Newton starts with a series $z = f(x)$ and obtains $x = f(z)$ by inverting it (Wolfram calls this reversing a series).

The method is to guess that $x \approx z$, so $x = z + p$, where $p$ is an error term.  $p$ can be evaluated by plugging into $f(x)$, and keeping only the simplest terms.  He gives two examples including deriving the sine from the inverse sine.  I have worked through these as well.

For this problem (the exponential), two cycles gives
$x = z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \dots$
which suggests I'm on the right track.

My two (related?) problems are:  (i) how to deal with the fact that the original series was for $\ln (1 + x)$ and (ii) I am missing the leading factor of 1 in the exponential series.

A change of variable turns into a mess.  I think I'm close but I'm not sure how to clean this up.

Comment: I would have thought if $z=\log(1+x)$ then $x=\exp(z)-1$ and it is $\exp(z)-1$ which is approximated by $z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots$, meaning  $\exp(z) \approx 1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots$

Comment: Yes.  Silly not to see that.